# Changing value of row based on condition in other condition

Tags: r

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Index Year Renovation
1      2012       1
1      2018       1
2      2012       1
2      2018       1
3      2012       0
3      2018       0
```

I would like to change the Renovation variable for 2012 to '0', IF the renovation variable for 2018 was "1". So I am facing a double condition here. How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` to check for condition.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Index) %>%
  mutate(Renovation = ifelse(Year == 2012 & 
                              Renovation[match(2018, Year)] == 1, 0, Renovation))

#  Index  Year Renovation
#  <int> <int>      <dbl>
#1     1  2012          0
#2     1  2018          1
#3     2  2012          0
#4     2  2018          1
#5     3  2012          0
#6     3  2018          0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Index = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Year = c(2012L, 
2018L, 2012L, 2018L, 2012L, 2018L), Renovation = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```